# How to develop regression tests for a calculation engine

Tags: testing, integration-testing, regression-testing

I'm on a team developing a financial information web app. We haven't written many automated tests for it yet, so we've decided to add regression tests to the most critical parts of our program. I'm very new to automated testing, though, so I'm not entirely sure how I should go about writing the tests.

This post is long, so here's the tl;dr question: How can I write a regression test that checks to see if certain calculation is working? I don't just want to test the calculation, though - I also want to know if any of the components the calculation depends on to give it its inputs break. I don't need to know which component broke in particular, just that something's not working. What approach should I use?

This is our situation: We developed the app using a layered architecture, like this:

```
Views
  |
  V
Logic Managers <--> Financial Calculation Engines
  |
  V
Data Accessors
  |
  V
Database
```

We've determined that the calculation engines are the parts of our program that most need to have a regression test suite. These components contain the calculations and algorithms that we use to process raw financial data into useful results. Their corresponding Managers use them by calling their public methods, which accept raw financial data as parameters. When the engine methods return, they send back an object that contains processed financial results. The managers, meanwhile, get the raw financial data from the data accessors, which in turn get data from the database.

We decided we want to know as soon as a financial calculation "breaks" so that we know the bug is somewhere in whichever pieces of the program have been touched since the last run of the tests. This would let us use continuous testing to protect us from having the engines producing wrong results and having no idea where to look.

When we thought about what this means, we realized that adding a unit test to each of the engines isn't enough. Let's say, for example, that an erroneous change to the data accessors means that they start pulling the wrong data. This data would then be sent up through the manager to the engine, which would produce the wrong results. However, the engine's algorithms themselves would still be working perfectly, so the unit test would still pass. This means that when we noticed the wrong numbers being generated, we would have no way of knowing when the bug was introduced, making it more difficult to track down and fix.

Instead, we would like to make regression tests that are able to pick up as soon as a bug appears anywhere that would cause the final results the engines output to be incorrect, even if the problem is that the wrong data is sent to the engines and not that the engines themselves have issues. When these tests fail, they wouldn't tell us where the problem is, but if we're continuously testing, we'll know as soon as a bug is checked in and have a small set of changes to look through to fix it.

So that's what we want to do. Unfortunately, we don't know how to create these tests. What approaches or patterns are useful for writing these types of regression tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint: you should check every part of the Financial Calculations Engine with **the same inputs every time**, and the objects returned should be **identical** every time.
Test separately the Data Accessors, with the same logic: same input, same output.
To do so, you need to [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) some parts of the system (eg. mock the data accessors to always return the same set of data).

Having separate unit tests fore each part also locates the bug with more precision.

A couple of links to get into the idea:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest/index.html
http://www.slideshare.net/joewilson123/unit-testing-and-mocking

There are a lot of mocking frameworks around that can help you code the tests, like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FeaturesAndMotivations) for Java projects.